# Strengthen Teeth

Tags: exercise, exercise-technique, physiology

Recently come into ownership of a large amount of very very tough beef jerky (I got it free because no one can eat it). And was quick to realize just how wimpy my teeth were.
Just a few stripes and my teeth were loosening, and I think I might have cracked one. My teeth were painful, continually, for days. So ...

How does one exercise/strengthen ones teeth in a healthy and safe manner to build up strength in the muscle/bone/cartilage/etc. that makes up the teeth and their connection to the jaw?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has little to do with physical fitness, and more to do with dental health.

Comment: "Physical fitness is your ability to carry out tasks without undue fatigue."

Comment: "Physical fitness is a general state of health and well-being and, more specifically, the ability to perform aspects of sports, occupations and daily activities."

Comment: I have never seen a definition of physical fitness that somehow excluded teeth. Chewing is as much a part of physical ability as walking.

Comment: Part of the issue is that we tend to focus on things that can actually be cured by exercise. The most likely case of loose teeth is gum disease with less likely cases of malnutrition and simple old age. Asking for exercises to help with it is a bit like asking for exercises to improve hair growth. Really, they don't exist.

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski - If you had read the site's guidelines for what is off-topic, rather than quoting some dictionary... http://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Agreed. Strengthening your jaw muscles won't do a thing to correct loose/fragile teeth. I know of no exercise routine that would do that.

Comment: @Alec Thanks for the link, that is even better than the explanation in the tour. It seems pretty straightforward that Teeth strengthening is pretty explicitly On-Topic then.

Comment: I can agree to disagree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, if you think you may have cracked a tooth, I highly recommend that you see a dentist. If your teeth are that loose, there is likely an underlying cause that you need to deal with comparable to someone with injuries having to be treated before being able to undertake strenuous exercises. However, I think you have a genuine question in there.

In general, exercise builds durability by applying mild strain, enough to bend but not break the body, where the body is healthy enough to undergo that strain. If you have been cleared by your dentist (because, as I noted in the comment above, [the most likely cause for loose teeth is gum disease](http://www.deardoctor.com/inside-the-magazine/issue-15/splinting-treatment-for-loose-teeth/)), you're going to want to start with someone with a small amount of firmness, but which you can't get your teeth lodged into. Sugarless bubble-gum is probably your best bet (chewing gum tends to be more "sticky" and might cause trauma). If you can get ahold of a dental appliance such as the [Y-Chew](http://www.arktherapeutic.com/blog/post/1203), that's probably even better. Your goal initially is not to apply a great deal of pressure, but rather to apply a moderate amount over a longer period of time by continuously chewing. If your body is in a decent shape, the mild trauma will cause your body to react by binding the teeth more securely with the useful side effect of also helping to strengthen your jaws. If your teeth are not in good shape (as per if your dentist did not medically clear you), you're likely to injure yourself further.

Outside of that, good dental health is really your primary line of defense. Rinse with a mouthwash that has a fluoride rinse at least daily, and brush your teeth 2-3 times a day (contrary to what might seem to be common sense, you're generally better off brushing before eating, as the primary goal is to remove plaque, and some foods can soften your teeth, making it so that your brushing removes enamel). One before heading off to bed and once in the morning isn't too bad of a plan. Also, don't forget to floss to get the food that gets stuck between the teeth, but be gentle, particularly with loose teeth.